# Kubernetes pods - why are there sometimes multiple processes?

Tags: kubernetes

My understanding is that, if a pod is configured to have one container, that container will run its "main" process as PID 1 and that's pretty much it. My pods have only one container each, and they very often have multiple processes running (always copies of the same process) - why does this happen?

On one cluster I have:

```
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root         1  0.3  0.4 276668 76076 ?        Ssl  16:50   0:48 python manage.py drive_consumer_worker
root        19  0.0  0.0  34432  2756 ?        Rs   20:28   0:00 ps aux
```

On another cluster (running the same `Deployment`), I have:

```
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root         1  1.2  0.3 1269420 104388 ?      Ssl  Mar16 240:12 python manage.py drive_consumer_worker
root        26  0.0  0.2 1044312 84160 ?       S    Mar16   0:01 python manage.py drive_consumer_worker
root        30  0.0  0.0  34440  2872 ?        Rs   20:30   0:00 ps aux
```

As you can see, the memory size is significant enough to indicate that it's a "real" process, but I don't know what I can do to continue debugging. I don't see any pattern with the number of pod replicas defined and the process count.

Snippet from the deployment definition:

```
      containers:
      - args:
        - newrelic-admin run-program python manage.py drive_consumer_worker
        command:
        - /bin/bash
        - -c
```

What is going on here?

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on the parent process, if it doesn't spawn any children the process `1` is all you'll have in the container. In this case, it looks like `python manage.py drive_consumer_worker` is spawning children processes, so it will be more up to the application to control if it spawns children as more processes in the container.

Comment: If I had to guess, you might be using something like multiprocessing or another worker pool system. These are commonly used in Python code to allow for concurrency without GIL muckery. Those all involve forking off a child process.